# Py: How to extract text with hashtag from image

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I am trying to extract "#opentowork" text from LinkedIn account thumbnails but it does not seem to work.

the image is:

[image]

I have tried the simplest way:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(r'1633367686467.jpg'))
```

And using opencv

```
img = cv2.imread('1516535608688.jpg', 0)
# img = 255 - img #invert image
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config = '--psm 12'))
```

But it returns nothing. I am not really experienced in text recognition. Is it possible to extract the text from such images?

Comment: You want to extract a text that you already know what it says or just detect which profiles have the opentowork tag? since this label is exactly always in the same place, it's opaque and has the same size, just checking for that specific color in the bottom left or doing some primitive image substraction will probably work. otherwise try some image detector and descriptor on that region. SIFT and SURF should suffice for that.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yeah I have to detect which profiles have the opentowork tag. With the color I am not sure how to detect it

Comment: you take one positive image and take a sample of pixels in the lower left corner. Then for each new image you check the color of pixels in that same spot and see if they are similar enough (Don't look for an exact match since image compression might create small artifacts). This should work almost always, except if for some reason there's something with the same exact tome of green in that zone. that's why taking a bunch of pixels is a good idea, a real object will most likely have a bit of variation in the tone of green (shadows, different angle...) that you will be able to detect.

Comment: take a tutorial on Opencv and it will take a few lines of code to do what you need  https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html  Then if you want more advanced things (not needed for this particular problem, but interesting to learn) you should learn about feature detectors and descriptors   https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d97/tutorial_table_of_content_features2d.html